# Feedforward neural network classification in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, pattern-recognition

I have two gaussian distribution samples, one guassian contains 10,000 samples and the other gaussian also contains 10,000 samples, I would like to train a feed-forward neural network with these samples but I dont know how many samples I have to take in order to get an optimal decision boundary.
Here is the code but I dont know exactly the solution and the output are weirds.

```
x1 = -49:1:50;
x2 = -49:1:50;
[X1, X2] = meshgrid(x1, x2);
Gaussian1 = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)], mean1, var1);// for class A
Gaussian2 = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)], mean2, var2);// for Class B
net = feedforwardnet(10);
G1 = reshape(Gaussian1, 10000,1);
G2 = reshape(Gaussian2, 10000,1);
input = [G1, G2];
output = [0, 1];
net = train(net, input, output);
```

When I ran the code it give me weird results.
If the code is not correct, can someone please suggest me so that I can get a decision boundary for these two distributions.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you really want. Can you be more specific describing your training set please?

Comment: In simple words, I want to find the accuracy of this feed forward NN, I want to draw a decision boundary of this classifier for this gaussian distributions. :)

Comment: To draw the decision boundary, this post may be of some assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502666/draw-divisory-mlp-line-together-with-chart-in-matlab/33503674#33503674

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the input must be the Gaussian distribution (and not the `x` coordinates). In fact the NN has to understand the relationship between the phenomenons themselves that you are interested (the Gaussian distributions) and the output labels, and not between the space in which are contained the phenomenons and the labels. Moreover, If you choose the `x` coordinates, the NN will try to understand some relationship between the latter and the output labels, but the `x` are something of potentially constant (i.e., the input data might be even all the same, because you can have very different Gaussian distribution in the same range of the `x` coordinates only varying the mean and the variance). Thus the NN will end up being confused, because the same input data might have more output labels (and you don't want that this thing happens!!!). 
I hope I was helpful.

P.S.: for doubt's sake I have to tell you that the NN doesn't fit very well the data if you have a small training set. Moreover don't forget to validate your data model using the cross-validation technique (a good rule of thumb is to use a 20% of your training set for the cross-validation set and another 20% of the same training set for the test set and thus to use only the remaining 60% of your training set to train your model).

Comment: It is true that I will use the gaussian distributions as input and label [0,1] as output.But I have one another problem, My first gaussian distribution has 100x100 = 10,000 samples and another gaussian distribution has also 100x100 = 10,000 samples total sample 20,000, I dont know how many samples I have to take to draw a reasonable decision between these two classes.

Comment: Correct me if I have mistaken to understand: you have a multivariate normal distribution (or a multidimensional gaussian) and you want to study the relationship of the probability distribution of the latter gaussian with some classes. Right? In that case you want your 100x100 matrix to be the features of your hypothesis function. Thus, why do you want to use a NN on this training set of only two examples?

Comment: I have two gaussians G1 and G2 and using Bayes theorem I have computed the posterior probabilities of these gaussians and then plot the decision boundary between these distribution, now my next task is to use the same gaussian distribution samples and apply these on Feed forward NN and compare the results. I hope this will clear the question meaning.

Comment: And you have calculated the posterior probability for all the samples in your Gaussians, getting one posterior probability for G1 and another one for G2, right?

Comment: Yes, in this case the prior probabilities are same (equal no. of samples), then I think the class conditional probability will be the same as posterior probability, after that I have used the discriminant function to find the decision boundary, but I am assigned the task to use the feedforward neural net and compare the results. Here is a best example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/feedforwardnet.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com, Can I have your personal email so that I can explain more details about this question, I shall be very thankful as the deadline for this is tomorrow.

Comment: The problem is that, to calculate the probability of the two Gaussian to belong to class A or B, you're using your two 100x100 matrices as a training set of two examples and not of 20000 examples. Thus the NN fails to calculate it because there aren't too much examples (i.e., only two, while you need at least tens of examples) from which learn the parameters for your hypothesis function. So it's normal that your NN doesn't fit very well the data.

Comment: You have to think of NN as a baby that needs tons of examples to learn even simplest thing, like the difference between the words mom and dad: if you give to this baby only a couple of examples he will not be able to learn it. 

P.S.: Sorry, but I think that we have a completely different time zone (I'm writing from Italy). That's why I'm not answer soon. However, if I'm still in time, leave me your email and I will contact you as soon as possible.